# Using ArcGIS Pro Vector tile package in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, vector-tiles, tile-package

Does anyone perhaps have a work around for reading a ArcGIS Pro Vector tile package in ArcGIS Desktop?

There is an option to open the online service in Desktop but raises an unsupported file type error when I select this option.

Comment: I think vector tiles are a Pro feature. Server can serve them (when federated to a Portal with a Data Store), but only Pro can create or consume them.

Comment: @Vince this is the answer...I cant find anything in the doc that says "ArcMap cant open a VTPK"...but yeah, this is the case.

Answer (score 2):

Simply, ArcMap can not open a vector tile package.
ArcGIS Pro and web applications are the only clients that can consume a VTPK.